# Facebook Follow button disappeared, how to figure it out what happened?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I've insert the following code and SDK, provided by Facebook, in a PHP widget code reader in front sidebar (homepage):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=162098443986551";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>`
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '162098443986551',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//findout-macau.com/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
```

};

```
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>`
```

It was working fine, but suddenly no longer showing.

My question is to know how can i figure it out what happened in order to try to fix it... my domain is http://findout-macau.com

Comment: That’s just the embedding of the JS SDK (done twice btw.) – but I can’t find the actual follow-button code anywhere in your page source.

Comment: I copy pasted the SDK code from facebook developers.

Comment: Well, then you might have copied only half of it – the code for the actual follow-button code is missing in your page.

Comment: I have the SDK code inside widget PHP code reader, is there any other place i should place it instead?

Comment: You should place the _actual follow-button code_ in there as well if you want a follow button …!

Comment: I've the follow-button code also inserted here. As following:
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=162098443986551";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

Comment: _Again_ – that is the code for embedding the JS SDK _only_, __it is not__ the follow-button code itself. Could you go back to the docs page now please and look at the code they give you there _thoroughly_ … thank you.

Comment: I've inserted only the iFrame code facebook provided, and it works...

Comment: How can i give you some credits for help solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there are supposed to be two divs with the same ID?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

appears twice in your code.